# Does fragrouter work with OpenVPN?

Tags: network, nmap, ids, openvpn

My goal is to evade IDS/IPS detection and scan the target with nmap. If the scan is detected, the target seems to stop responding for 10s. I think that IP Fragmentation Attack is exactly what I need.

So I tried to scan with `-f` and `-ff` flags and have actually seen fragmented packets in Wireshark, but my scan apparently was blocked. Nmap doesn't work **as evasion attack** but it does perform a fragmentation itself. As far as I know nmap doesn't implements the fragment *overlap* technique therefore I tried to use `fragrouter` instead.

First I specified the `tun0` interface, but got the `"fragrouter: sniff_init failed: unknown physical layer type 0xfffe"` error. I specified the actual physical adapter `eth0` and saw no difference with regular scan in the traffic dump. Fragmentation wasn't performed **at all**. My main idea was if a packet goes to `tun0`, it should go through `eth0` too. Even if a packet is being sent to `tun0` via loopback, `sudo fragrouter -i lo -T1` doesn't work too because of the `"unknown physical layer type 0x304"` error.

Looks like OpenVPN reassembles it before sending to the target network or I made a mistake in the process. I even tried to change the `MTU size` in the OpenVPN config using the `mssfix` and `tun-mtu` options (connection simply didn't start). My working OpenVPN configuration includes `proto tcp`, `nobind`, `comp-lzo`, `persist-tun`, `persist-key` options.

My question is why nmap fragmentation works, but not `fragrouter`? What should I do to launch `fragrouter` with OpenVPN?

Comment: You never describe the VPN in your set up. Where does that fit?

Comment: You appear to say that nmap fragmentation didn't work, then you said it does. Can you clarify that?

Comment: I mean that Nmap fragemntation doesn't work **as evasion attack** but fragmentation is present instead of fragrouter that do nothing with packets.
I launch the OpenVPN client on Kali 2022. Config contains `proto tcp`, `nobind`, `comp-lzo`, `persist-tun`, `persist-key`.

Comment: @kseniapi please add this information into the question, thank you